# Trouble getting started with Django Channels

Tags: python, django, nginx, django-channels, daphne

I am creating my own application inspired from the [Channels 2.0 tutorial](http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_2.html). However, I am unable to establish WebSocket connection. Daphne complains for 404 saying the websocket URL can not be found. I am not sure where the error is.

**UPDATE**: My Daphne is running behind an nginx server. The nginx config is updated as well:

My directory structure is as follows

```
- SomeDashboardProject
  |-- Dashboard
    |-- asgi.py
    |-- settings.py
    |-- urls.py
    |-- routing.py
    |-- ...
  |-- WebSocketTest
    |-- consumers.py
    |-- routing.py
    |-- urls.py
    |-- views.py
    |-- templates
        |-- WebSocketTest
            |-- index.html
```

**WebSocketTest/templates/WebSocketTest/Index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dashboard_id = '1';

    var chatSocket = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.host +
        '/ws/dboard/' + dashboard_id + '/');

    chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
        var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        console.log(data);
    };

    chatSocket.onclose = function(e) {
        console.error('Chat socket closed unexpectedly');
    };

</script>
```

**WebSocketTest/views.py**

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'WebSocketTest/index.html', {})
```

**WebSocketTest/consumers.py**

```
class TestConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):

    def connect(self):
        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        pass

    def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']
        print(message)
```

**WebSocketTest/routing.py**

```
websocket_urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^ws/dboard/(?P<dashboard_id>\d+)/$', consumers.TestConsumer),
]
```

**WebSocketTest/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

**Dashboard/routing.py**

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(
                    WebSocketTest.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
            )
    )
})
```

**Dashboard/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^test/', include('websockettest.urls'), name='test'),
]
```

**Daphne Error log**

```
2018-06-12 02:41:58,857 WARNING  Not Found: /ws/dboard/1/
None - - [12/Jun/2018:02:41:58] "GET /ws/dboard/1/" 404 974
```

**Nginx.conf**

```
upstream home {
  server unix:///Users/pranavprakash/workspace/SomeDashboardProject/nginx.sock;
}

# configuration of the server
server {
  # the port your site will be served on
  listen      80;
  # the domain name it will serve for
  server_name localhost; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
  charset     utf-8;

  # max upload size
  client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

  # Django media
  location /media  {
    alias /Users/pranavprakash/workspace/SomeDashboardProject/media;
  }

  location /static {
    alias /Users/pranavprakash/workspace/SomeDashboardProject/staticfiles;
  }

  # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
  location / {
    uwsgi_pass  home;
    include     /Users/pranavprakash/workspace/SomeDashboardProject/uwsgi_params;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a little bit of search, I found it's an issue with Nginx config. The nginx config I posted does not allow websockets. The following change needs to be done:

```
location / {
    uwsgi_pass  home;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    include     /Users/pranavprakash/workspace/SomeDashboardProject/uwsgi_params;
  }
```

More details available at the [Nginx blog post](https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/)